# Dar estilo a botones CSS HTML

Tags: html, css, botón, div

Automáticamente me salen los **botones** uno debajo del otro al repartirlos en 3 divs.

Cada **botón** tiene su propio **div** y a su vez todos los **divs** están en un **div** llamado **botones**.

**¿Cómo puedo repartir los tres botones en un ancho X centrados?** Sin que ocupen todo el ancho de la página pero sí un 60% o 70% de la página y centrados con un espacio entre cada botón de 10 px (padding).

```
<div class="botones">
    <!-- Botón NUEVA cabaña -->
    <div class="boton_anadir_cabana" class="table-responsive" align="left">
        <font face="verdana">
            <b><input type="button" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="nueva_cabana" id="nueva_cabana" value="Añadir cabaña" /></b>
        </font>
    </div>

    <!-- Botón ELIMINAR cabaña/s -->
    <div class="boton_eliminar" class="table-responsive" align="left">
        <font face="verdana">
            <b><input type="submit" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="eliminar_cabanas" id="eliminar_cabanas" value="Eliminar cabañas" /></b>
        </font>
    </div>

    <!-- Botón NUEVO accesorio -->
    <div class="boton_anadir_accesorio" class="table-responsive" align="left">
        <font face="verdana">
            <b><input type="button" style="width:200px; height:28px;" name="nuevo_accesorio" id="nuevo_accesorio" value="Añadir accesorio" /></b>
        </font>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.botones{
    width: 70%;
    float:left;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Captura del croquis:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes utilizar flex-box, por ejemplo:

```css
.button-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px; 0;
    width: 50%;
    border: thin solid gray;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-container">
    <input type="button" name="name" value="Button1" />
    <input type="button" name="name" value="Button2" />
    <input type="button" name="name" value="Button3" />
</div>
```